# Why isn't my message box functioning?

Tags: javascript, php

I have to do 1 system that have add process and edit process. In these process I already put coding of message box but when I try it, I found that the message box does not work. I want when user does not finish fill their information and already click submit button the message box come out.

Can someone help me to fix this problem? Here is the code:

```
<?php
include("authenticationStaff.php");
include ("dbase.php");  

        $query= "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE staff_name ='".$_SESSION['SESS_STAFF_NAME']."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);


        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $id = $row["id"];
        $staff_id=$row["staff_id"];
        @mysql_free_result($result);

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function Validate()
{
    if (document.addStaff.project_name.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Project Name!');
       document.addStaff.project_name.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.project_id.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Project ID !');
       document.addStaff.project_id.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.location.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Location!');
       document.addStaff.location.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.cost.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Cost!');
       document.addStaff.cost.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.pic.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Person In Charge!');
       document.addStaff..pic.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.detail.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Detail about the Project!');
       document.addStaff.detail.focus();
       return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table width="869" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
       <td width="645" height="50" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Welcome ,&nbsp; You log in as &nbsp; &nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_STAFF_NAME'];?> </strong></td>
      <td width="224" align="right" valign="middle"><strong><a href="logout.html" title="Logout">Log Out</a></strong></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   <?php
   $idURL = $_GET['id'];
   $query ="SELECT *
    FROM staff s
    JOIN inter1 i
    ON (s.staff_name=i.staff_name)";

$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die("Could not execute query");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH); // using numeric index or array index

    $staff_id = $row['staff_id'];
    $project_name = $row['project_name'];
    $location = $row['location'];
    $detail = $row['detail'];
    $pic = $row['pic'];
    $staff_name = $row['staff_name'];
    $project_id = $row['project_id'];


    @mysql_free_result ($result);
?>
   <center>
  <form action="addStaff_process.php?id=<?php echo $idURL; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="add_process" id="add_process" onsubmit="return Validate()" >
  <table border="1" width="70%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="6" >
  <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >STAFF NAME:</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="staff_name" cols="50" rows="2" id="staff_name"><?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_STAFF_NAME'];?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >STAFF ID:</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="staff_id" cols="50" rows="2" id="staff_id"><?php echo $idURL; ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >PROJECT ID:</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="project_id" cols="50" rows="2" id="project_id"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >PROJECT NAME :</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="project_name" cols="50" rows="2" id="project_name"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >LOCATION :</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="location" cols="50" rows="2" id="location"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" > COST :</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="cost" cols="50" rows="2" id="cost"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="" >
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >PERSON IN CHARGE :</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="pic" cols="50" rows="3" id="pic"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">DETAIL ABOUT THE PROJECT:</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
        </table>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>
          <input class="form-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="return Validate()"/>
          <input type = "reset" value = "RESET" />
        </p>
  </form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an extra period between addStaff and pic in this line: `document.addStaff..pic.focus();`

Comment: What is `document.addStaff`? Do you mean to use `document.getElementById('addStaff')` or something similar?

Comment: @armadadrive message box still does not come out..

Comment: This problem appears to be with your JavaScript and should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

`addStaff` is a not a property or method of the `document` object. Therefore, your conditional tests are going to fail every time and none of the code in your `if` statements will run.

I believe you are looking for something along the lines of:

```
if (document.getElementById("project_name").value == "") {
    //Your error handling code...
}
```

Comment: Great! Please mark this as the correct answer (the check mark) if it worked for you. :)

Comment: armadadrive why this message box something came out sometime does not come out??

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.